# How to use Persian text in Android?

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8

I have some problem with Persian text in Android.
I get a page code with ION library and load it in a text view but the Persian text changes to `?` characters:

[image: sample image]

Comment: Would you explain more? Are you sure you receive the right utf characters from server (Have you tested it with postman?)

Comment: tnx for helping yes i recive a html page that is utf-8 encoding (thats a instagram page link)

Comment: Would you post your xml code?

Comment: no i just get a instagram page code with ION library and i split some txt and get them but in persian text it change to ? char

Answer (score 0):

my xml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:backgroune3d="#f9faf9">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txttest"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```